# How to define angular's @Input decorator in an interface?

Tags: angular, typescript, decorator

Given is the following Angular component:

```
export class NumberComponent implements NumberInterface {
  @Input() number;
  constructor() { }
}
```

Now I'm looking forward to implement the `NumberInterface`. That's what I've got so far:

```
export interface NumberInterface {
  number: number
}
```

Basically, I'm using the type `Function` to define the Decorator. Now I'm wondering if there is a more specific way to do this. The interface should force the component to implement angular's `@Input` decorator.

Comment: `NumberComponent implements NumberInterface` isn't a thing in Angular. Despite the name, it's not a _class interface,_ but simply a _collection of types._

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Interfaces in Typescript strictly do not have value, as they are entities that only exist for type-checking and are not compiled into JS.

You can't define a decorator in an interface because the decorator has *value*. It's a function that takes an argument and gives value to the class property, and not a type.

Angular's `@Input` decorators themselves do have a typing, but it's impossible to type them in a lower-order class since that property is itself already a type, but given *value* by the decorator:

```
export interface ITest {

  prop: Input;
  prop2: InputDecorator;

}

export class Test implements ITest {

  @Input('thing') prop: string;
  @Input('thing2') prop2: string;

}

// typeerror: Test does not correctly implement ITest
```

However, component classes can be derived from in Angular, and the parent class' decorators will be inherited by the child. This is useful if you want to implement strong typing alongside a more polymorphic approach to your code:

```
export class NumberBase {

  @Input('number') number: number;

}

export class NumberComponent extends NumberBase {


  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.number); // works!
  }

}
```

Components can extend either plain TS classes or fully decorated Angular components.

Comment: Thanks, `extending` brings exactly the behavior I want. Such a brilliant answer!

Comment: I believe `super()` needs to be called in the component's `constructor()` then since it's extending a class

Comment: yup, if you have a constructor, the `super` call needs to be the first line of the constructor body. The TS compiler will let you know that pretty quickly :)